# What is the difference between hypothesis, thesis statement and research goal?

Tags: thesis, terminology

Can someone explain the difference between *hypothesis, thesis statement* and *research goal* based on an example?

Comment: You should mention which subject you are in. 'Hypothesis' has opposite meanings in maths and physics.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same question recently and did some research on it. The definitions I found weren't consistent, but from them I derived the following.

**Thesis statement** -- A definitive statement about the way the world (or your system of interest) works, especially what is most important in causing or influencing the behavior of the system.

> "Family expectations has primary significance on the performance in college for Latino girls in the Western US" is an example of a thesis statement.

**Research goal** -- Expresses what you hope to learn or shed light on in your research.  Specifically, the goal should specify what *type* of results you are hoping to achieve. It contextualizes your work in relation to other research, especially theory.  It also feeds into your choice of method.

> "My research goal is to develop a theoretical model of cultural influence on college performance, contextualized by gender and ethnicity" is an example of a research goal.

**Hypotheses** -- What *specific* conditions or relations do you aim to test or evaluate in your research.  Any research that does not include a method for hypothesis testing should *not* claim to test hypotheses. A hypothesis statement must be specific enough that it is testable by the methods you choose, and also it should be falsifiable -- i.e. it is clear what evidence might prove the hypothesis false, and such evidence should be plausible and possible.

> "Low family expectations has a detrimental effect on the college completion rate and time-to-complete for high-achieving Latino girls" is an example of a hypothesis statement.

Notice how there are specific, testable conditions and metrics -- "college completion rates" and "time-to-complete".  These conditions should appear as metrics in your research methods -- i.e. instruments and analysis methods.

Answer (score 3):

A thesis statement usually helps guide the research paper. It is a short sentence or summary containing the central idea of the research paper. It helps a reader have a clear glimpse of what the paper is about.

The Hypothesis statement comes in different format but with the intent to help prove or disprove a phenomenon. The hypothesis can help defend, support, explain or disprove, argue against the thesis statement.Usually the hypothesis measures specific issues or variables-two or more and therefore should be testable. The thesis statement creates a background while the hypothesis creates a means to measure the interrelationship.

The research goal takes a look into the future of your study or research paper. |It tries to help you state what the outcomes you seek to achieve by the research work. With a research goal you can set specific milestones to accomplish at the end of the research work.